# Prestashop - how to rename name of the page?

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

What I need is to rename name of the page and the link.

This is from tutorial:

> the body’s id is module-testmodule-allproducts.  Again, this is a
>   pattern: `module-*modulename*-*controllername*`. This is also the name
>   for this page. It’s pretty ugly, but we have the ability to change it
>   if really needed. Let’s edit our init() method as follows:

```
public function init()
{
$this->page_name = 'allproducts'; // page_name and body id
parent::init();
}
```

> Refresh the page. You’ll now notice the body id has changed,
>   reflecting our variable assignment.

This code didn't work for me.

Comment: The code is working perfectly here, so you should explain more detailed the step you are performing, like in which class do you add this code, which controller are you invoking, etc.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I need to know how to rewrite the link because this module will be used to creat a new page with a specific templat.The link in adress bar is : http://www.sitename.com/index.php?fc=module&module=testmodule&controller=allproducts   I don't want this kind of link.